# How to add Column Values from 2nd DataFrame Based on Some Column Values in First dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My 1st DataFrame is so:

```html
RowCol  Value_Pre
Key1 234
Key3 235
Key2 235
Key4 237
```

My Second Dataframe is:

```html
RowCol  Value_Post
Key3 235
Key1 334
Key4 237
Key2 435
```

How to create a third dataframe like a the one below by combining the two dataframe

```html
RowCol  Value_Pre Value_Post
Key1  234 334
Key3 235 235
Key2 235 435
Key4 237 237
```

How to develop this code in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['Value_Post'] = df1['RowCol'].map(df2.set_index('RowCol')['Value_Post'])
print (df1)
  RowCol  Value_Pre  Value_Post
0   Key1        234         334
1   Key3        235         235
2   Key2        235         435
3   Key4        237         237
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, especially if necessary append multiple new columns:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='RowCol', how='left')
```

Comment: How do you create another column with values depending if Value_Pre is not equal to Value_Post?

Comment: @Adhil - Do you think `df1['new'] = np.where(df1['Value_Pre'].ne(df1['Value_Post']), 10, 20)` ?